# bash valid request returns nil when performed on ruby and HttParty

Tags: ruby, bash, http-post, httparty

I'm using [HttParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for my requests, for what I created the following custom class:

```
class MyRequestClass
  include HTTParty

  def initialize(base_uri)
    self.class.base_uri base_uri
  end

  def post(endpoint, options, headers)
    self.class.post(endpoint, :body => options.to_json, :headers => headers)
  end
  ...
end
```

From a service module, i try to make a POST as the following:

```
def post_method
  options = { "tenantId" => "tenantId", "username" => "nn@gmail.com", "password" => "password", "rememberMe" => "1", "timestamp" => Time.now.to_i }
  headers = { "Content-Type" => "application/json", "X-NI-signatureType" => "2", "X-NI-signatureHash" => "my_sign_hash", "X-NI-apiKey" => API_KEY, "X-NI-apiVersion" => "1" }
  req = RequestParty.new(BASE_URI).post("/user/authenticate", options, headers)
end
```

But i get req = nil.

Not sure what am I missing/doing wrong, because the same request made from a bash works fine:

```
export TIMESTAMP=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
export URL="http://my-site/user/authenticate"

echo -n $(iconv -c -f UTF-8 -t US-ASCII <<EOF
{
  "tenantId": "tenantId",
  "username": "nn@gmail.com",
  "password": "password",
  "rememberMe" : 1,
  "timestamp": "${TIMESTAMP}"
}
EOF
) >${BODY}

curl -v --connect-timeout 10 -m 20 -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "X-NI-signatureType: 2" \
  -H "X-NI-signatureHash: ${SIG}" \
  -H "X-NI-apiKey: ${API_KEY}" \
  -H "X-NI-apiVersion: 1" \
  -d @${BODY} \
  $URL 2>&1 
rm ${BODY}
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: either content or an error. Thou looking at it on chrome's networks console it seems like the request is never performed, for some reason..

Comment: It may be the same request, but we have no way of knowing that without seeing the contents of the file named by `$BODY` or the value of `$URL`.

Comment: got it @chepner. Just edited my post with that data.

Comment: Where do you use MyRequestClass? Where do you call `post_method`?

Comment: post_method is inside a module called ASDService, @Jordan